# Issue in regex in angular 13 cli

Tags: regex, angular13

**About**

I am using Angular 13 CLI. There is input type textbox with validation to support only small and upper case characters but due to some reasons, it is allowing to accept other than letter also.

**Component - Js**

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

    public accountForm: any = null;
    
    constructor() {
        this.accountForm = new FormGroup({
            first_name: new FormControl("", [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.minLength(3),
                Validators.maxLength(10),
                Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)
            ])
        });
    }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
        
    }
}
```

**Html**

```
<form [formGroup] = "accountForm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="first_name" [value]="this.userData.first_name" />
    <span *ngIf="this.accountForm.controls.first_name.errors && this.accountForm.controls.first_name.dirty ">
        <ng-container *ngIf="this.accountForm.controls.first_name.errors.required; else second">
            This is required
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #second>
            <ng-container *ngIf="this.accountForm.controls.first_name.errors.minlength; else third">
                min length error
            </ng-container>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #third>
            <ng-container *ngIf="this.accountForm.controls.first_name.errors.maxlength; else fourth">
                max length error
            </ng-container>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #fourth>
            <ng-container *ngIf="this.accountForm.controls.errors.pattern">
                Invalid format for first name
            </ng-container>
        </ng-template>
    </span>
    <button>Submit</button>
    
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late for the answer.

You miss out on specifying the form control (`first_name`) for displaying the pattern error.

```
this.accountForm.controls.errors.pattern
```

It should be:

```
this.accountForm.controls.first_name.errors.pattern
```